# How do Switch statement work with Symbols?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, symbols

I'm new to JavaScript. Excuse if stupid question.

The following snippet makes sense. Nothing out of the ordinary:

```
const RED = 'red';
const ORANGE = 'orange';
const YELLOW = 'yellow';
const BLUE = 'blue';
const cat = 'blue';

function getThreatLevel(color){
  switch(color){
    case RED:
      return 'severe';
    case ORANGE:
      return 'high';
    case YELLOW:
      return 'elevated';
    case BLUE:
      return 'low';
    default:
      console.log("I DON'T KNOW THAT COLOR!")
  }
}
```

`getThreatLevel(BLUE)` = 'low'

`getThreatLevel(cat)` = 'low'

However, when changing the type of the first 4 variables to Symbols:

```
const RED = Symbol('red');
const ORANGE = Symbol('orange');
const YELLOW = Symbol('yellow');
const BLUE = Symbol('blue');
const cat = 'blue';

function getThreatLevel(color){
  switch(color){
    case RED:
      return 'severe';
    case ORANGE:
      return 'high';
    case YELLOW:
      return 'elevated';
    case BLUE:
      return 'low';
    default:
      console.log("I DON'T KNOW THAT COLOR!")
  }
}
```

`getThreatLevel(BLUE)` = 'low'

`getThreatLevel(cat)` = 'I DON'T KNOW THAT COLOR!'

Why does `cat` no longer return 'low'?

Comment: Because a `string` is not a `Symbol` -> [Symbols don't Auto-Convert to "strings" (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol#Symbols_don't_Auto-Convert_to_strings)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, `cat` and `BLUE` hold the same value, the immutable string `"blue"`.

In the second example, `cat` and `BLUE` hold **different** values.

As an aside, each call to Symbol produces a unique value. So two different Symbols with the same description (which is only for debugging purposes) *are* different.

```js
console.log('blue' === 'blue');
console.log(Symbol('blue') === 'blue');
console.log(Symbol('blue') === Symbol('blue'));
```

Comment: Thank you. I see where my source of confusion stemmed from. Does JS treat cases as string by default if no variables / symbols are readily available to map?

`case BLUE:` was treated as a string in the first instance thereby matching against `const Blue` and `const cat`. However, `case BLUE:` in the second instance is only matched against the Symbol `BLUE`

Comment: @Digitful – "Does JS treat cases as string by default" — No. It's an expression. `BLUE` is a constant so the expression resolves as the value of the constant. If you hadn't defined it, then it would be a Reference Error. (and you never defined `const Blue`, only `const BLUE`)

Comment: Got it. Thank you